# State value is resetting to its initalState when a new value is set using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a simple App component that is handling the state of a value to show a header. With an onClick function, I'm setting the `isHeaderVisible` value to True in the `Home` component when a logo is clicked and another route is used.

```
import React from "react";

interface HomeProps {
  setIsHeaderVisible: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
}
const Home: React.FC<HomeProps> = ({ setIsHeaderVisible }) => {
  const handleLogoClick = () => {
    setIsHeaderVisible(true);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <a href="/tester" onClick={handleLogoClick}>
        <img src={"https://picsum.photos/200"} alt="Tester Logo" />
      </a>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

When the logo is clicked, I can see isHeaderVisible being set to true but it then changes back to the initialState of false.

```
import React from "react";

interface HeaderProps {
  isHeaderVisible: boolean;
}
const Header: React.FC<HeaderProps> = ({ isHeaderVisible }) => {
  console.log("HERE", isHeaderVisible);

  return (
    <>
      {isHeaderVisible && (
        <header>
          <nav>
              <a href="/">Home</a>
              {/*<a href="/about">About</a>*/}
              {/*<a href="/contact">Contact</a>*/}
          </nav>
        </header>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Is this caused by the rendering the header when `isHeaderVisible` is set to True? I want to show the header on the page opened by clicking the logo on the `Home` component, in this example it would be the `Tester` component.

The code can be checked out in this [Codepen](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/divine-shape-5pjklj?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clply2dq300062e67fvdkq5yr%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clply2dq300022e67yxdfiuvf%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clply2dq300032e67vgt4zbev%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clply2dq300052e67ory8e950%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clply2dq300022e67yxdfiuvf%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clply2dq300022e67yxdfiuvf%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%257D%252C%2522clply2dq300052e67ory8e950%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clply2dq300052e67ory8e950%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clplyovq000n72e67a99t29qb%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clplyovq000n72e67a99t29qb%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clply2dq300032e67vgt4zbev%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clply2dq300032e67vgt4zbev%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are navigating using an `<a>` in Home.tsx.  That actually causes the browser to unload the page that has your React app in it, and then load a new page (`/tester`) that essentially starts up your React app again.

In a React single page application (SPA), you want to use a library such as React Router to do navigation within the app.  React Router "changes the URL" in the browser but does not actually cause the browser to unload the current page and load a new page.  It does some DOM / browser magic to keep the current page (your React app) loaded.

I got it working in CodeSandbox, but clearly it is having issues today.  I got it working locally on my machine and then I had to futz around with CodeSandbox to get it to refresh using my updated code.

[See it here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/smoosh-waterfall-2hf9s8?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clply2dq300062e67fvdkq5yr%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clply2dq300022e67yxdfiuvf%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clply2dq300032e67vgt4zbev%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clply2dq300052e67ory8e950%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clply2dq300022e67yxdfiuvf%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clply2dq300022e67yxdfiuvf%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%257D%252C%2522clply2dq300052e67ory8e950%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clply2dq300052e67ory8e950%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clpm08pb700ci3b6hqy8ez3v0%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpm08pb700ci3b6hqy8ez3v0%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clply2dq300032e67vgt4zbev%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clply2dq300032e67vgt4zbev%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D).